# Find occurrences of a string in a given element.

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am looking for a way to find instances of a certain character within a certain element. I am aware of doing something like:

```
var string = 'this is a string';
string.indexOf('a');
```

however, i want indexOf to look at a particular tag within a particular html file. (in this case, p tags). I have commented out what i tried to use in order to achieve this.

```
function findQuestion() {

  // var string1 = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

  var string2 = '??';
  if (string2.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
    console.log('foundQuestion');
  }
  else {
    console.log('nothing');
  }
}

findQuestion();
```

This code obviously just checks to see that there is a '?' in string2, but how do i write this to find all instances of '?' within p tags and return all content preceding that up to the opening p tag in which the '?' was found?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you could do that:

1. Get all `p` elements.
2. Create an empty array, results
3. Iterate over them and check for each p element
4. If the p's innerHTML contains a question mark split the string at the question mark, get the first part and add a question mark. Then add this new string to the results array
5. Return the results array

Example Code:

```
function findQuestion() {

  var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){
    var p = ps[i];
    if (p.innerHTML.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
        result.push(p.innerHTML.split("?")[0] + "?");
    } 
  }

 return result;

}

findQuestion();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3o4tcchL/1/

Comment: @Kevmannn I hope it works for you. If it does please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer, this will show your question was answered and will give you and me some reputation. Please also consider accepting answers in your other questions, since you haven't accepted any answers yet. People will be more motivated to help you if you accept answers.

Comment: ahh. thanks. New to SO and programming in general. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop condition to check the entirety of the content within

, after that use something like slice, which will grab everything up to a particular index you specify.